# Extract the exact number of elements from the same identifier

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, text-formatting

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Id       Chr     Start   End    
Prom_1   chr1    3978952 3978953  
Prom_1   chr1    3979165 3979166  
Prom_1   chr1    3979192 3979193  
Prom_2   chr1    4379047 4379048  
Prom_2   chr1    4379091 4379092  
Prom_2   chr1    4379345 4379346  
Prom_2   chr1    4379621 4379622  
Prom_3   chr1    5184469 5184470  
Prom_3   chr1    5184495 5184496
```

and I would like to count how many times the same identifier appear. Something like:

```
Prom_1  3  
Prom_2  4  
Prom_3  2
```

Any idea is really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk

```
awk 'NR>1 {a[$1]++} END { for (x in a) { print x,a[x] } } ' file
```

The `NR>1` will ignore the header
`a[$1]++` is a hash iterator

Answer (score 4):

With [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html)

```
$ datamash -W --header-in groupby 1 count 2 < file
Prom_1  3
Prom_2  4
Prom_3  2
```

Comment: "groupby" does not work. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Tommi - it's alternative syntax for  `--group` or `-g`

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about datamash.

Comment: I have tried --group and does not work but -g yes. So +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can count the identifiers with `uniq`:

```
tail -n +2 input | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c
```

Note that `uniq` expects sorted input. We use `tail` to skip the header and `cut` to 'cut-out' the first column.

Example output:

```
  3 Prom_1
  4 Prom_2
  2 Prom_3
```

In case an id with a smaller number should be printed before an id with a larger number (e.g. `Prom_3` before `Prom_10`) you can replace `sort` with `sort -V` (version sort):

```
tail -n +2 input2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -V | uniq -c
```

Example output (input2 contains an extra line for id `Prom_10`):

```
  3 Prom_1
  4 Prom_2
  2 Prom_3
  1 Prom_10
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way with cat, cut , sort and uniq is :

```
sed -n '1,$p' input | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: 2 issues: 1) will also count the header, i.e. the output will include the line `1 id` 2) the use of `cat` is useless

Comment: Which way you will prefer to read file??

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to user3589054:

since there are a lot of Id, when you sort you will not have the same order of Id because for example the Id starting with Prom_1 Prom_10 etc.. will be as first. So what i did was this and it worked fine:

`awk 'NR>1 {a[$1]++} END { for (x in a) { print x,a[x] } } ' file | awk -F "_" '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"}' | cut -f 2 | sort -n | awk -F " " '{print $1"\t"$2}' | sed 's/^/Prom_/' > file.output.txt`

where:
`awk 'NR>1 {a[$1]++} END { for (x in a) { print x,a[x] } } ' file |`
you will have the output with the Id and number but not sorted

`awk -F "_" '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"}' |` 
you will split the file in Prom , number, its Id number and its quantity

`cut -f 2 | sort -n |`
sort according the number Id and its correspondent amount

`awk -F " " '{print $1"\t"$2}' |`
here you tab the two columns

`sed 's/^/Prom_/'`
and finally you attach the Prom_ in front of its number Id

Comment: You should indent your code such that it is properly rendered. Btw, if you want that the numerical part of you id is numerically sorted you can just use `sort -V` instead of a plain `sort`. Then it is still sufficient to just cut out the first column.